# How to embed Twitter timeline in Angular 6 application

Tags: angular

I'd like to embed a Twitter timeline into an Angular 6 application, but I couldn't find a good solution. This is what I've tried:

- Place Twitter generated code from 'publish.twitter.com' into the index.html.
- Install `ngx-twitter-timeline` package. I got this warning because I'm using Angular 6 and RxJS 6, so I uninstalled it:

[image]

- Install `ng4-twitter-timeline` package. It seems to have critical vulnerabilities:

[image]

How could I get it? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 18):

You don't need to install any package:

**index.html**:

```
<head>
   <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
```

**app.component.html**:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">
   Tweets by TwitterDev
</a>
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    (<any>window).twttr.widgets.load();
}
```

Source: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/overview.html

Comment: is there any problem if I call the widgets.load() function inside ngOnInit?

Comment: @JosephJojoJohn You'll run the risk that your HTML content (`<a class="twitter-timeline"...`) is not loaded. And if it doesn't exist, it can't load.

Comment: i had to do an additional delay of 1 sec but this solution works best! THX

Answer (score 0):

As I've read, there's no Angular-only way of getting the Twitter timeline due to CORS security mechanism. However, I found some good tutorials to do it using NodeJS, like this one:

http://thelillysblog.com/2017/02/26/getting-twitter-feed-angular-nodejs/

Answer (score 0):

To embed twitter timeline in Angular there are 2-3 packaged available, I have used this one it works fine, Also is has many other functionalities.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-twitter-widgets

## Install Package

```
npm i ngx-twitter-widgets
```

### Add NgxTwitterWidgetsModule to imports list in module file

```
...
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxTwitterWidgetsModule
],
...
```

### Use timeline in component file

```
<ngx-twitter-timeline
  [source]="{sourceType: 'profile', screenName: 'StackOverflow'}"
  [options]="{height: '400'}" (onLoad)="onLoad($event)">
</ngx-twitter-timeline>
```

Here is documented properly...
https://romikmakavana.github.io/ngx-twitter-widgets